# PHP installation source

Tags: php, installation, makefile

often we get a pack and made configure as habitual. I'm trying to set a dev enviorment with Apache (already installed), SQL and PHP. Curiosly, the PHP introdue a source tree  slightly different of the habitual, with a collection of files named Makefile.global, Makefile.gcov, Makefile.objects and Makefile.fragments (or something as, relying version). The ask simple: what is this 'new concept' and how to make it effectively.
Thanks.

Comment: You're right, what you describe is unconventional. As such, we could only guess about the intended usage.  Have you considered consulting the project's documentation for instructions on how to build and install it?

Comment: Yes, I ever consider it. Sry english is not native language.
Further, the official php documentation doesn't offers this information. Intended...?